# google apps script concatenate merge

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

looking for this function to be built into sheet using a script- not a "custom Function"

user adds data into Sheet1

**Sheet 1**

```
  -----a--------b   
1    fName     lName
2
3
```

**Sheet 2** AutoPopulates on each edit

```
 -----a--------b   
1         fName_lName
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo code for an `onEdit(event)` function:

```
Use the attributes of the `event` object

Find which row has been edited
If there is text in column A & B of this row
  Set value of column B to `A + '_' + B`
  And clear A
```